# AngularJS, UI-Router and SEO - my trick works but need improvement

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

My site is implemented using AngularJS + ASP.NET MVC. For client routing I using UI-Router.

In order to make my site visible by search engines, after some research I conducted, I realized that probably the best way achieve that is to pre-render requested views (this way, for any given URL the whole page got served and no additional AJAX is required).

So, it works - but I have a problem. This is what happened when some URL is requested:

1. Server receive web request. It generates the whole view, and returns it. That view already contains 'ui-view' placeholder for future navigation (it prefilled with page content).
2. Scripts get loaded. Angular initialized, and UI-Router sets state for that URL, overwriting content inside 'ui-view'
3. As a result (and here is a problem), the user for very short period see page, and after few seconds part of it (stuff inside 'ui-view') got refreshed.

Why it is a problem? Well, for example, if that part contains input and user already started to type something inside, after a few seconds (just when Angular get loaded) that part will be refreshed and everything will be deleted. Very annoying.

So, I think that the direction for solving that is to somehow prevent from UI-Router from loading initial state - but I don't know how to do that.

Any ideas? Maybe different approach?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Apply [`ng-clock`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak) to `ng-view` and any other sections that you don't want to blink before Angular compiles html

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't works. The problem is because it takes time to bring Angular.js from CDN. So: initial page loaded (with content inside), and after Angular.js downloaded everything is reloaded. So - that is not a problem of seeing "un-compiled angular".

Comment: Read the article referenced in answer. There are also CSS classes required. `ng-cloak` is the canonical way for dealing with troubles you expreience